# I get NullPointerException when populating a ListView component

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a main class (its layout is BorderPane) that has a search text field and when you input something and press the button beside it, it should then show a list of the String that is associated with the inputted word. I use an AnchorPane to contain the ListView but whenever I try to populate that ListView, I get a NullPointerException. The fx:id is correct and I've tried everything and went through a lot of other answers but nothing seems to be working :(

**This is my main class**

```
public class MMFXApp extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene startScene, resultsScene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 750));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Magnet");
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    public void closeApplication() {
        System.out.println("Application clossing...");
    }
}
```

**This is the main controller for that main class**

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField searchtext;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainpane;

    @FXML
    public void searchButtonClicked() {
        System.out.println("Searching....");
        if ((searchtext.getText() != null && !searchtext.getText().isEmpty())) {
            System.out.println("Inputted text: " + searchtext.getText());
            RecommendedMedia rm = new RecommendedMedia(searchtext.getText());
            mainpane.setCenter(rm);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing was inputted.");
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is the class that extends AnchorPane that I hope will display the list**

```
public class RecommendedMedia extends AnchorPane {

    private String search;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> reclist;

    public RecommendedMedia(String search) {
        this.search = search;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("recmedia.fxml"));
        ArrayList<String> recs = getRecs();
        reclist.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(recs));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getRecs() {
        ArrayList<String> recs = new ArrayList<String>();

        // I'm adding stuff in a list manually for now
        recs.add("Captain America - The Frst Avenger");
        recs.add("Iron Man III");
        recs.add("Thor - The Dark World");

        return recs;
    }
}
```

**And this is the stack trace when I click the button**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fyp.RecommendedMedia.<init>(RecommendedMedia.java:26)
    at com.fyp.Controller.searchButtonClicked(Controller.java:20)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Yes, there may be a real fix to what you already have, but what I recommend is that you DON’T use reflection. It will really simplify your code.

Comment: @JacobB.: there isn't any reflection in this code.

Comment: @JacobB. `FXMLLoader` is responsible for the reflection and it's not the root cause of the exception...

Comment: @Brian oh rip me i see. I scrolled right to the stack trace and saw reflection and red flags went up haha. My bad.

Comment: @fabian yeah i see now. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements from the fxml are injected during the `FXMLLoader.load` call. Trying to access them before results in the NPE you observed.

Do

```
reclist.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(recs));
```

after

```
fxmlLoader.load();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I though it wouldn't make a difference if I put it before the load().

Answer (score 0):

some times if you don't declare fx:id in your FXML for ListView can cause NullPointerException issue. so always make sure your definition of your objects are completely right. NullPointerException is really tricky and some times it is hard to find the issue.
also to trace the issue, you can put break point at the mentioned line number in Errors, so you can debug your program and check the values to find null value issue.